# imported .owl files have #'s in prefixes vs original rdf4j triplestore

Tags: sparql, owl, virtuoso, graphdb, rdf4j

When I import the dump "PathwayCommons12.All.BIOPAX.owl.gz" ([linked from this page](https://www.pathwaycommons.org/archives/PC2/v12/?C=S;O=D)) of [this Virtuoso triplestore](https://rdf.pathwaycommons.org/), I've noticed that there are "#"s inserted after the prefix of various URIs.

In particular, the following query [runs on the original endpoint](https://rdf.pathwaycommons.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fpathwaycommons.org&query=PREFIX%20pfx%3A%20%3Chttp%3A%2F%2Fpathwaycommons.org%2Fpc12%2F%3E%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%3Fpw%20%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%3Fpw%20a%20bp%3APathway%0D%0Avalues%20%3Fpw%20%7Bpfx%3APathway_c2fd3d95c8c65552a0514393ede60c37%7D%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=0&debug=on):

```
# Query 1
PREFIX pfx: <http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/>

select ?pw 
where {
?pw a bp:Pathway
values ?pw {pfx:Pathway_c2fd3d95c8c65552a0514393ede60c37}
}
```

But to get it running on the local endpoint (imported owl dump) I have to add a "#" to the end of `pfx:` like:

```
# Query 2
PREFIX pfx: <http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/#>

select ?pw 
where {
?pw a bp:Pathway
values ?pw {pfx:Pathway_c2fd3d95c8c65552a0514393ede60c37}
}
```

Note that Query 1 works only on the original endpoint, while Query 2 works only on the local endpoint.

What is going on here?

Comment: I'm wondering about the versions of Virtuoso in use on the different endpoints; specifically, whether they differ. You can check with [this SPARQL query](http://vos.openlinksw.com/owiki/wiki/VOS/VirtCheckSvrVersionViaSparql). Note that https://rdf.pathwaycommons.org/ is offline, so we can learn little remotely...

Comment: Thanks @TallTed, yes that endpoint went down for emergency maintenance after the question was posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we look at the first few lines of that massive RDF/XML file, we see:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rdf:RDF
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:bp="http://www.biopax.org/release/biopax-level3.owl#"
 xml:base="http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="">
 <owl:imports rdf:resource="http://www.biopax.org/release/biopax-level3.owl#" />
</owl:Ontology>

<bp:ExperimentalForm rdf:ID="ExperimentalForm_ee10aeab-1129-49ad-8217-4193f4fbf7e0">
 <bp:comment rdf:datatype = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">[ExperimentalFormVocabulary_bait]</bp:comment>
 <bp:experimentalFormDescription rdf:resource="#ExperimentalFormVocabulary_701737e5cf53d06134cbd3ee59611827" />
</bp:ExperimentalForm>
```

Note the value of the `rdf:ID` attribute here: "ExperimentalForm_ee10aeab-1129-49ad-8217-4193f4fbf7e0". This is a relative URI, and needs to be resolved against the base URI (which is declared in the document header: "http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/"). How this resolution is supposed to happen is described in [section 2.14 of the RDF/XML syntax specifcation](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#section-Syntax-ID-xml-base):

> The rdf:ID attribute on a node element (not property element, that has another meaning) can be used instead of rdf:about and gives a relative IRI **equivalent to # concatenated with the rdf:ID attribute value**. So for example if rdf:ID="name", that would be equivalent to rdf:about="#name".

(emphasis mine)

[Example 16](https://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-syntax-grammar/#example16) in the specification illustrates this further.

What it comes down to is that in parsing this RDF/XML, the values supplied as `rdf:ID` attributes all resolve to `http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/#<ID>`. So the result you're getting in GraphDB is correct for the given input. Why it is different in the Virtuoso endpoint I don't know: either they used a different input file, or they have a bug in their parser, or whatever tool was used to produce this dump file contains a bug.

It is probably safe to say that the *intent* of whoever created the dump file was that
`rdf:ID="ExperimentalForm_ee10aeab-1129-49ad-8217-4193f4fbf7e0"`  would resolve to the IRI `http://pathwaycommons.org/pc12/ExperimentalForm_ee10aeab-1129-49ad-8217-4193f4fbf7e0` (that, is without the added `#` character). There are several ways to fix this in the file: either replace all occurrences of `rdf:ID` with `rdf:about`, or else don't rely on relative URI resolution and just use the full URI as the `rdf:ID` value.

Comment: thanks, this is extremely helpful.  two further questions: 
1) would I be correct to assume that people usually intend for resources to take the form "base#<ID>" as in ex16?
2) if so how likely is it that something is messed up with the virtuoso configuration thats spitting out resources lacking the "#"s, instead of the dump?  like, have you ever seen the intentional omission of the "#"s at other endpoints?

Comment: I'm not really sure what people _usually_ intend when they use an rdf:ID, but the RDF/XML syntax spec says that when you use rdf:ID with a value that is not already an absolute IRI, the only possible outcome is an IRI with a # in it.

Comment: The subtle differences between processing an rdf:about and an rdf:ID attribute value in RDF/XML are a well-known cause for bugs in parsers and writers - including some past cases I have seen where a parser forgot to append the # to the rdf:ID value before resolving it. So that seems to me the most likely cause: there's a RDF/XML parser or writer somewhere in the tool chain that incorrectly assumes you can create an absolute IRI from a base URI and a rdf:ID value without sticking a # in between.

Comment: Suffice to say that RDF/XML is a difficult syntax form to get right, and you're usually better off with something like turtle or n-triples.